# select data from a table and return it as an array in django

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-views

I have a table that has a column `evidence` and I want to `count` the number of rows that contain a particular evidence number. For instance 100 rows may have evidence number value as 003, 200 rows may have evidence number value as 004 etc.

I have tried this:

```
distinct_evidence=Tzworksjmplist.objects.values('evidence').annotate(evidence_count = Count('evidence'))
    distinct_evidence=list(Tzworksjmplist.objects.values('evidence').annotate(evidence_count = Count('evidence')))
```

and the result is:

```
[{'evidence_count': 6119, 'evidence': u'002'}, {'evidence_count': 6119, 'evidence': u'003'}, {'evidence_count': 6119, 'evidence': u'004'}, {'evidence_count': 6119, 'evidence': u'010'}, {'evidence_count': 6119, 'evidence': u'020'}, {'evidence_count': 6119, 'evidence': u'030'}, {'evidence_count': 6119, 'evidence': u'040'}];
```

I want it to return data in this format:

```
[['Evidence 003', 12], ['Evidence 44', 9], ['Evidence 005', 14], ['Evidence 33', 16], ['Evidence 002', 7], ['Evidence 666', 9]];
```

Someone please give an insight on how I achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end:

```
result = [['Evidence %s' % e['evidence'], e['evidence_count']] for e in distinct_evidence]
```

Anyway, I don't understand why evidence number is a CharField.

Comment: Thanks pythonishvili, evidence should be an integer,it your answer served my purpose

Comment: How do i remove the u in the result? The result is [[u'Evidence 2', 6119], [u'Evidence 5', 6119], [u'Evidence 7', 6119]];

Comment: `u` prefix means that the string is in fact a unicode. And unicode is a good thing. Leave the `u` be unless you explicitely nee it to be an oldschool string, eg. to compare with another string. To convert to string use `str(u'unicoded string')`